# Interrupt Enter Key On ContentEditable Div In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, contenteditable

I want to interrupt the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and stop it from injecting the html code into the `ContentEditable` div.  My current code does not work because it does not interrupt the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  However, if I type, press <kbd>enter</kbd>, then type again, it deletes the inner html elements.  But still, this is not what I want.  I want the elements to NOT go into the `ContentEditable` div to begin with when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> rather than having to strip them out.

I am essentially using this as an *"input that scales with its content"*.  If there is a better way to do this, please let me know!

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class MyInput extends React.Component {    
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({value: nextProps.html});
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    return nextProps.html !== ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).innerHTML;
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if ( this.htmlEl && this.props.html !== this.htmlEl.innerHTML ) {
     this.htmlEl.innerHTML = this.props.html;
    }
  }

  emitChange(){
    var html = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).innerHTML;

    // regex to remove tags created after pressing enter
    value = value.replace(/<div>/g, '');
    value = value.replace(/<\/div>/g, '');
    value = value.replace(/<br>/g, '');

    if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
      this.props.onChange(html);
    }
    this.lastHtml = html;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    var html = this.state.value;
    return (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}
        onInput={this.emitChange.bind(this)}
        onBlur={this.emitChange.bind(this)}
        contentEditable
      ></div>
    )
  }
};<kbd>
```

Comment: This is kind of confusing. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I realize that there were some mistakes (I ported this from something I'm working on and left old logic in there).  What kind of example are you looking for?

Comment: Mainly your question is just worded badly. Its unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I don't really see how the question is confusing.  As stated, I want to interrupt the enter key in a content editable div in ReactJS.  For instance, when I press enter, I want to submit the information in the content editable div.  However, when you press enter in a content editable div, the DOM inserts <div> tags and <br> tags in order to account for a "new line".  My current solution strips the excess <div> and <br> tags out, but I want to catch the enter key stroke BEFORE the event propagates and changes the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind you div with a keyboard event and then:

```
var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
keyCode === 13 && event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
  //  function handler inside class declaration
  keyPress(event) {
    if(event.charCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }

  //  in render function
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}
    onInput={this.emitChange.bind(this)}
    onBlur={this.emitChange.bind(this)}
    onKeyPress={this.keyPress.bind(this)}
    contentEditable
  ></div>
```